# Iterable multiprocessing Queue not exiting

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing.queues as queues
import multiprocessing
class I(queues.Queue):
    def __init__(self, maxsize=0):
        super(I, self).__init__(maxsize)
        self.length = 0 

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def put(self, obj, block=True, timeout=None):
        super(I, self).put(obj,block,timeout)
        self.length += 1

    def get(self, block = True, timeout = None):
        self.length -= 1
        return super(I, self).get(block, timeout)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.length

    def next(self):
        item = self.get()
        if item == 'Done':
            raise StopIteration
        return item


def thisworker(item):
    print 'got this item: %s' % item
    return item

q=I()

q.put(1)
q.put('Done')

the_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1)
print the_pool.map(thisworker, q)
```

I'm trying to create an iterable queue to use with multiprocessing pool map.
The idea is that the function `thisworker` would append some items to the queue until a condition is met and then exit after putting 'Done' in the queue (I've not done it here in this code yet)

But, this code never completes, it always hangs up.

I'm not able to debug the real cause.
Request your help

PS: I've used `self.length` because the `map_async` method called from under `the_pool.map` requires to use the length of the iterable to form a variable: `chunksize`, which will be used to get tasks from the pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're treating `'Done'` as a special-case item in the `Queue`, which indicates that the iteration should stop. So, if you iterate over the `Queue` using a for loop with your example, all that will be returned is `1`. However, you're claiming that the length of the `Queue` is 2. This is screwing up the `map` code, which is relying on that length to accurately represent the number of items in the iterable in order to know when all the results have returned from the workers:

```
class MapResult(ApplyResult):

    def __init__(self, cache, chunksize, length, callback):
        ApplyResult.__init__(self, cache, callback)
        ...
        # _number_left is used to know when the MapResult is done
        self._number_left = length//chunksize + bool(length % chunksize)
```

So, you need to make the length actually be accurate. You can do that a few ways, but I would recommend not requiring a sentinel to be loaded into the `Queue` at all, and use `get_nowait` instead:

```
import multiprocessing.queues as queues
import multiprocessing
from Queue import Empty

class I(queues.Queue):
    def __init__(self, maxsize=0):
        super(I, self).__init__(maxsize)
        self.length = 0 

    ... <snip>

    def next(self):
        try:
            item = self.get_nowait()
        except Empty:
            raise StopIteration
        return item


def thisworker(item):
    print 'got this item: %s' % item
    return item

q=I()

q.put(1)

the_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1)
print the_pool.map(thisworker, q)
```

Also, note that this approach isn't process safe. The `length` attribute will only be correct if you only `put` into the `Queue` from a single process, and then never `put` again after sending the `Queue` to a worker process. It also won't work in Python 3 without adjusting the imports and implementation, because the constructor for `multiprocessing.queues.Queue` has changed.

Instead of subclassing `multiprocessing.queues.Queue`, I would recommend using the `iter` built-in to iterate over the `Queue`:

```
q = multiprocessing.Queue()
q.put(1)
q.put(2)
q.put(None)  # None is our sentinel, you could use 'Done', if you wanted
the_pool.map(thisworker, iter(q.get, None)) # This will call q.get() until None is returned
```

This will work on all versions of Python, is much less code, and is process-safe.

**Edit:**

Based on the requirements you mentioned in the comment to my answer, I think you're better off using `imap` instead of `map`, so that you don't need to know the length of the `Queue` at all. The reality is, you can't accurately determine that, and in fact the length may end up growing as you're iterating. If you use `imap` exclusively, then doing something similar to your original approach will work fine:

```
import multiprocessing

class I(object):
    def __init__(self, maxsize=0):
        self.q = multiprocessing.Queue(maxsize)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if hasattr(self.q, attr):
            return getattr(self.q, attr)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        item = self.q.get()
        if item == 'Done':
            raise StopIteration
        return item


def thisworker(item):
    if item == 1:
        q.put(3)
    if item == 2:
        q.put('Done')
    print 'got this item: %s' % item
    return item

q=I()

q.put(1)
q.put(2)
q.put(5)

the_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)  # 2 workers
print list(the_pool.imap(thisworker, q))
```

Output:

```
got this item: 1
got this item: 5
got this item: 3
got this item: 2
[1, 2, 5, 3]
```

I got rid of the code that worried about the length, and used delegation instead of inheritance, for better Python 3.x compatibility.

Note that my original suggestion, to use `iter(q.get, <sentinel>)`, still works here, too, as long as you use `imap` instead of `map`.

Comment: Very nice explanation. But, I have a further doubt over your answer. As you might have noticed in my question, the funcion `thismethod` needs to keep appending to the queue until a particular condition is met. And, there will be x number of such `thisworker` processes running. Does your solution also work in that case ?

Comment: @GodMan So, `thisworker` will be adding items to the `Queue` in addition to consuming from it?

Comment: @GodMan Also, does only one instance of `thisworker` need to put `'Done'` in the `Queue` for all of them to stop working?

Comment: Yes. the workers will also be adding items to the queue and they will dequeue (`queue.get`) from the queue as well. Based on the dequeued data, the worker will be putting more items in the same queue. Thats why I want to ask whether your solution works in this case as well ?

Comment: If only one instance of worker puts 'Done' then some other worker will read that `Done` and again put `Done` back in the queue  (for other workers to finish) and finish.

Comment: @GodMan I'm confused...why are you trying to use `map` to iterate over the `Queue` and feed items to the workers, if the workers are directly consuming from the `Queue` using `queue.get` anyway? Why not just start up your workers and have them call `queue.get` in a loop, and just drop the iterable `Queue` idea altogether?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63175/discussion-between-godman-and-dano).